# Can't set a coma separator using implode() on an array in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, implode

Can't set the correct separator for array conversion to string. I am using

```
echo .implode(  ",", $terms_array ).;
```

The output is: **array1array2array3** instead of **array1,array2,array3**

In sandbox it works fine, but when I put code to WordPress, it's not working.

What can be a reason?

```
function wc_show_attribute_links_prodcart() {
    
    global $post;
    $attribute_names = array( 'pa_attr1', 'pa_attr2','pa_attr3' ); 
        
    foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $attribute_name );
        
        if ( $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $taxonomy ) ) {
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name );
            $terms_array = array();
        
            if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                   $archive_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute_name );
                   $full_line = '<a href="' . $archive_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
                   array_push( $terms_array, $full_line );
                }
                //echo .implode(  ",", $terms_array );
             echo implode( ',', $terms_array );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the content of `$terms_array` in you're question. Your asking us why a function isn't working with a variable we have no clue about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating your three `$attribute_names`.

If `$taxonomy` is truthy, you are clearing out your `$terms_array` each time.

You are imploding and printing at the end of each outer loop, so there will be no comma between what you are calling `array1` ...etc.

To better visualize the output, use a linebreak `<br>` at the end of your echo.

Or if you want all hyperlinks to be comma-separated, just declare a master array to collect them all then implode when you are done.

```
function wc_show_attribute_links_prodcart() {
    global $post;
    $hyperlinks = [];

    foreach (['pa_attr1', 'pa_attr2', 'pa_attr3'] as $attribute_name) {
        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($attribute_name);
        if ($taxonomy && !is_wp_error($taxonomy)) {
            foreach (wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $attribute_name) as $term) {
                $archive_link = get_term_link($term->slug, $attribute_name);
                $hyperlinks[] = '<a href="' . $archive_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo implode(',', $hyperlinks);
}
```

Or with all hyperlinks separated per group and groups visibly separated:

```
function wc_show_attribute_links_prodcart() {
    global $post;
    $all_term_links = [];

    foreach (['pa_attr1', 'pa_attr2', 'pa_attr3'] as $attribute_name) {
        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($attribute_name);
        if ($taxonomy && !is_wp_error($taxonomy)) {
            $term_links = [];
            foreach (wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $attribute_name) as $term) {
                $archive_link = get_term_link($term->slug, $attribute_name);
                $term_links[] = '<a href="' . $archive_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
            }
            $all_term_links[] = implode(' & ', $term_links);
        }
    }
    echo implode(',', $all_term_links);
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/  wp_get_post_terms() returns an array so it can be fed directly to the `foreach()`.

Comment: Great! It solved my issue! I used second snippet with hyperlinks separated per group